# R Plotly: How to add text to links of sankey diagram?

Tags: r, plotly, sankey-diagram

I created a sankey diagram using plotly and R with three columns. I want to add text on the links, so that you see the value of the links without the need to hover over them. Here's some sample code. I tried out annotations but could not get it to work.

```
# Create data.table with counts
dt <- dt[, .N, by=c("column_a", "column_b", "column_c"]

# Create nodes
nodes <- c(unique(dt$column_a), unique(dt$column_b), unique(dt$column_c))
    
# Create links
links <- data.table(
  source=c(match(dt$column_a, nodes)-1, match(dt$column_b, nodes)-1),
  target=c(match(dt$column_b, nodes)-1, match(dt$column_c, nodes)-1),
  value=c(dt$N, dt$N)

# Collapse links
links <- links[, .("value" = sum(value)), by=c("source", "target")]

# Plot Sankey diagram
fig <- plot_ly(
  type="sankey",
  orientation="h",
      
  node=list(
    label=nodes
  ),
      
  link = links)

# create annotations for flows
annotations <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(links)) {
  source_x <- # x-coordinate of source node
  source_y <- # y-coordinate of midpoint of source node
  target_x <- # x-coordinate of target node
  target_y <- # y-coordinate of midpoint of target node
  label <- links$value[i] # create label
  annotations[[i]] <- list(
    x = (source_x + target_x) / 2, # x-coordinate of annotation
    y = (source_y + target_y) / 2, # y-coordinate of annotation
    text = label, # set text to label
    showarrow = FALSE # hide arrow
  )
}

# add annotations to plot
fig <- fig |> layout(
  annotations = annotations
)
```

I tried out looping over the links and add an annotation to each but struggled to find the right coordinates of each link. How do I extract the coordinates of the links of a plotly sankey diagram? Furthermore, when the user changes the position of the nodes (and links), the text should stick to their labels.